# Django. Две модели в одном queryset

Tags: python, django

У меня есть две модели Post и File. У них есть одинаковое поле 'created_date'. как сделать выборку из базы сразу обоих моделей, чтобы отсортировать их по этому полю?

Comment: Скорее всего у каждой модели - свои таблицы. Можно, разве, что сделать `related` поле и делать а-ля `prefetch_related`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sort_items_by_date(list_of_classes):
    list_of_objects = []

    for cls in list_of_classes:
        for obj in cls.objects.filter(active=True):
            list_of_objects.append(obj)

    return sorted(list_of_objects, key=attrgetter('created_date'))
```

Вообщем вот так вот работает, но все-таки хотелось бы прямым запросом.